# The transaction was aborted by user then tried to collect statistic on table in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I tried to collect the statistic on my table this way:

```
COLLECT STATISTICS COLUMN (PURCHASE_ID) ON
     ONLINE_BANKING.TRANSACTIONs;
```

But Teradata returned this error:
*The transaction was aborted by user[3110]*.

The table contains about 12 millions rows. I'm using Teradata express edition 15.1 installed on virtual machine. And the table was created this way:

```
 SHOW TABLE ONLINE_BANKING.TRANSACTIONs;

CREATE SET TABLE ONLINE_BANKING.TRANSACTIONs ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      transaction_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      purchase_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      date_of_transaction DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD' NOT NULL,
      amount_of_transaction DECIMAL(38,2) NOT NULL,
      transaction_type_code BYTEINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 25 )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( transaction_id );
```

What is wrong here? I really need to collect this stats.

**upd1**: Seems to be that I'm using  Teradata syntax (not ansi).

[image: ansi]

Comment: In my experience, receiving a 3110 error suggests the aborted transaction was user initiated. It is possible the 3110 is encountered if the connection was disrupted during the execution of the transaction. What were the transaction semantics for the session? ANSI or Teradata.

Comment: @RobPaller Seems to be Teradata